# 1046 type not found on [spark.skins]::IHighlightBitmapCaptureClient

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I've made an ActionScript Mobile project in Flash Builder 4.5 and am getting this error that I can't fix.

> 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant [spark.skins]::IHighlightBitmapCaptureClient.

The error does not link to any source.

The project is basically the source to Flixel's FlxCollisions demo, but trying to compile it for iOS.

Using the same src folder (flxCollisions and Flixel 2.5) in a plain Actionscript project does not cause this error and runs as expected.

I've tried creating an empty AS Mobile project with a trace('hello'): that worked fine. Nothing in the project is using spark.skins.

How can I get rid of this error? What should I be looking at, or for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue and my main class embeds a preloader like so:

```
[Frame(factoryClass="Preloader")]
public class Main extends Sprite
```

Commenting that line out makes the error go away.

However, this wasn't what I wanted, so I went off and added the following SWC folders as dependencies:

```
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/sdks/4.5.0/frameworks/libs
/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/sdks/4.5.0/frameworks/locale
```

Which fixed all the errors. But I will still need to carefully go through the build path and yank out all the unwanted code.