# AS3 Mobile preloader using [frame] metadata tag: how?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, frame, preloader

I'm trying to create an AS3 pure preloader based on the [frame] metadata/compiler tag,
having exactly the same problem as Glutnix has [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785253/1046-type-not-found-on-spark-skinsihighlightbitmapcaptureclient). I'm also working on an AS3 ***Mobile*** Project.

I didn't want to re-ask the same question in that topic, since the solution posted there did not work for me. So i thought i'd ask it again, more specific to my own situation.

So i'm running into the same compiler error:

**1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:[spark.skins]::IHighlightBitmapCaptureClient.**

Also, 35 CSS-selector warnings like the following:

**Cannot resolve namespace qualified type 'ActionBar' in CSS selector 'ActionBar'**

I've tried the solution posted in the earlier-mentioned stackoverflow post, namely including the /libs and /locale folder from the 4.5 SDK, but that resulted in a new (larger) batch of errors:

**Unable to resolve resource bundle "collections" for locale "en_US".**

and the same errors for the following resource bundles: 
*components, core, effects, layouts, skins, styles*.

Also, 210 (!) warnings of the like:

**Cannot resolve namespace qualified type 'ActionBar' in CSS selector 'ActionBar'**

I have 2 questions, actually, about this problem:

1) what is actually going on here? am i force-referencing the 4.5 SDK so that it cannot find certain stuff or something?

2) Does anyone have the same problem? and if so, how did you solve- or work-around this? have you not used the [frame] preloader but another way of preloading?

Thanks for any contributions to this problem!

Michael

I'm on Mac OSX Snow Leopard, running FB 4.5 standard (non php-edition)

Comment: Do you have any sample code you can put up that isn't working?

Comment: Iif you're embedding classes via properties, it'll reference weirdo stuff in the flex sdk -- try making a new class for each embed.  (This is of course, if you're actually not using flex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems i asked this question a while ago and forgot to add the answer:

I don't remember why i wanted a preloader for a mobile app to begin with because they don't need preloaders as the app is ofcourse on the mobile device (downloaded & installed).

so the answer is: It's not needed